# Update using entities is randomly failing

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have 2 tables

```
         (1)        (N)
Transmit -------------<  Messages
---------------          -----------
TransmitId (PK)          TransmitId (PK)
InternalId               SendingDate (PK)
LastStatus               Content
MessageType              Answer
                         Status
```

In the edmx, it is well recognized as a 1-* relation.

Using entities to update them (this code is in a Sub called with a previously obtained transmitId)

```
Try
    Using db As New MyDBEntities
        
        ' Send the message to WebService
        FullResp = api.MessagesPostWithHttpInfo(td)
        
        ' Transmit
        Dim t As Transmit = db.Transmit.Find(transmitId)
        t.InternalId = FullResp.Data.id
        t.LastStatus = If(FullResp.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, Pionira.Status.Success, Pionira.Status.Failure)
        
        ' Message
        With t.Message.OrderByDescending(Function(j) j.SendingDate).First() ' Latest of message table
            .Answer = ApiClient.ReadAsBytes(ApiClient.Serialize(FullResp))
            .Status = t.LastStatus
        End With
        
        ' Commit changes in DB
        db.SaveChanges()
        
    End Using
    
Catch ex As Exception
    Return System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable
End Try
```

The code is called 77 times and on average, it is throwing an exception 2/3 of the time
The exception is :

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
> number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
> entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

I'm on my PC, local DB, alone at home, there is no way that there is any concurrent access to the rows that I'm trying to update.

As a result, my Message table is looking like this (2 is a succesfull update, 0 is not)

```
TransmitId  SendingDate             Content Answer  Status
1084        2021-03-18 16:05:36.547 [BLOB]          0
1085        2021-03-18 16:05:37.583 [BLOB]          0
1086        2021-03-18 16:05:38.630 [BLOB]  [BLOB]  2
1087        2021-03-18 16:05:39.687 [BLOB]          0
1088        2021-03-18 16:05:40.787 [BLOB]          0
1089        2021-03-18 16:05:42.100 [BLOB]  [BLOB]  2
```

I don't understand why it is sometimes working and sometimes not.
Please note that trying again and again is not giving the same rows in success or not. Usually I have between 22 and 29 (out of 77) that updates successfully but never ever all of them.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like I'm pointing out the obvious here, but doesn't the exception your getting explain exactly what is happening and even suggests a resolution?  Sounds very much like the collection of entities you've got in memory is getting out of sync with the DB

Comment: As stated, I'm on a local machine, nobody but me is using the DB. I'm reading a row from Transmit (that comes with an attached Collection of Message). I'm updating that row as well as one of the element in the collection. Finally I want to persist my changes. It seems very obvious and straight forward but it doesn't work. I'm a 100% sure that the DB did not change between my read and my db.SaveChanges instruction.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself doesn't appear to have any glaring issues. The DbContext is scoped correctly for the operation so I don't think it is memory state out of sync, though I am a bit suspicious of the statement that it is called "77 times on average".

Are these synchronous calls in a loop or just events triggered over the course of a user operation? I would be looking closely how this code is called (such as involving worker threads?) as well as any other code interacting with these tables. Provided your production code is scoping the DbContext within a `Using` block and that wasn't a change made just for your example.

If the example code is accurate then my guess would be that you either have overlapping calls due to perhaps worker threads or some other process interacting with transmits or messages while these numerous calls are being made. EF attempts to work with optimistic locking by default so it isn't difficult to encounter race conditions on data.

One suggestion I can offer is to avoid this:

```
    Dim t As Transmit = db.Transmit.Find(transmitId)
    With t.Message.OrderByDescending(Function(j) j.SendingDate).First()
```

This will trigger a lazy load of the Messages collection. Instead, you can use projection to get the data in one call:

```
Dim data = db.Transmit
    .Where(Function(t) t.TransmitId = transmitId)
    .Select(Function(t) New With {Transmit = t, Message = t.Message.OrderByDescending(Function(j) j.SendingDate).First() })
    .Single()
```

(Had to look up anonymous types in VB.Net:) so forgive if syntax is off.)

This will give you a data structure where you can get the Transmit (data.Transmit) and the latest message (data.Message) without reloading the entire set of messages.

Comment: To answer your question about the 77, it is a read from a file (very basic open, for each line call the code above then close). No threading nor tasks involved I think. Your suggestion seems a good idea and a legit cause of failing if it is a lazy load. I'll try that and keep everyone posted.

Comment: Yeah, calling a method like this in a loop while processing a file should be fine provided the DbContext is scoped with the `Using` block in the method.  Let us know how it goes and possibly expand your question example to include the processing loop code calling the method, and the code as it is in the project as that might be hiding a key detail for the behaviour.

Comment: It is a POC, you almost already have the whole Form1.vb :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've tried the projection way, it is not working better.
I had to modify it slightly because First() was not authorized there.
Here is the modified code:

```
Dim data = db.Transmit
    .Where(Function(t) t.TransmitId = transmitId)
    .Select(Function(t) New With {.pt = t, .js = t.JsonMessages.OrderByDescending(Function(j) j.SendingDate).FirstOrDefault()})
    .Single()
```

Let me put the whole Form1.vb, so you can picture the whole thing

```
Imports Pionira.Api
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports log4net
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Private Property exceptionLogger As ILog

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim reader as StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("json.txt")
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        For Each line In reader.ReadLine
            Dim td As Model.TransportDocument = api.Configuration.ApiClient.Deserialize(line, Models.TransportDocument)
            Dim transmitId As Integer = StoreInDB(td, Pionira.Models.TransportDocument, Pionira.Status.Ready)
            Dim resp As String = String.Empty
            Dim rc As System.Net.HttpStatusCode = SendTransportDocument(transmitId, td, resp)
        Next
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Sub

    Public Function SendTransportDocument(transmitId As Integer, td As Model.TransportDocument, resp As String) As System.Net.HttpStatusCode

        Dim FullResp As ApiResponse(Of Model.TransportDocumentReturnState)

        Try
            Using db As New MyDBEntities

                ' Send the message to Pionira
                FullResp = api.V2TransportDocumentsPostWithHttpInfo(td)

                Dim data = db.PioniraTransmit.Where(Function(t) t.PioniraTransmitId = transmitId).Select(Function(t) New With {.pt = t, .js = t.JsonMessages.OrderByDescending(Function(j) j.SendingDate).FirstOrDefault()}).Single()

                ' PioniraTransmit
                data.pt.PioniraId = FullResp.Data.id
                data.pt.LastSendingStatus = If(FullResp.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, Pionira.Status.Success, Pionira.Status.Failure)
                data.pt.LastHttpStatusCode = FullResp.StatusCode

                ' JsonMessages
                data.js.ReceivedAnswer = ApiClient.ReadAsBytes(ApiClient.Serialize(FullResp))
                data.js.SendingStatus = If(FullResp.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, Pionira.Status.Success, Pionira.Status.Failure)
                data.js.HttpStatusCode = FullResp.StatusCode

                ' Save response in DB
                db.SaveChanges() ' PioniraTransmit

            End Using

            resp = ApiClient.Serialize(FullResp.Data, True, True)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable
        End Try

        Return FullResp.StatusCode

    End Function

    Private Function StoreInDB(obj As Object, type As Integer, status As Integer) As Integer
        Dim existingPioniraTransmit As List(Of PioniraTransmit)
        Dim pt As New PioniraTransmit With {.MessageType = type,
                                            .Id = DirectCast(obj, Model.TransportDocument).externalId,
                                            .LastSendingStatus = status}

        DirectCast(obj, Model.TransportDocument).extraProperties.TryGetValue("OrderNr", pt.WDOId)

        Dim Json As String = ApiClient.Serialize(obj)

        Using db As New MyDBEntities
            existingPioniraTransmit = db.PioniraTransmit.Where(Function(m) m.Id = pt.Id).ToList()
            If existingPioniraTransmit.Any Then
                pt = existingPioniraTransmit(0) ' There can only be one
                pt.LastSendingStatus = status
            Else
                db.PioniraTransmit.Add(pt) ' Or 0, then add one
            End If
            pt.JsonMessages.Add(New JsonMessages With {.SendingDate = Date.Now(), .SendingStatus = pt.LastSendingStatus, .MessageSent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json)})
            db.SaveChanges()
        End Using
        Return pt.PioniraTransmitId
    End Function

    Dim api As Api

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        exceptionLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("ExceptionLogger")
        exceptionLogger.Info("Application Start")
        api = New Api("http://localhost:48096/")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        ' Close connections if needed
    End Sub
End Class
```

And my "real" tables for good measure (remember that it is a POC, it will change).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PioniraTransmit](
    [PioniraTransmitId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PioniraId] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [Id] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [WDOId] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [LastSendingStatus] [smallint] NULL,
    [MessageType] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [LastHttpStatusCode] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Pionira] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PioniraTransmitId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JsonMessages](
    [PioniraTransmitId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SendingDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [MessageSent] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ReceivedAnswer] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [SendingStatus] [smallint] NULL,
    [HttpStatusCode] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_JsonMessages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PioniraTransmitId] ASC,
    [SendingDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JsonMessages]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_JsonMessages_PioniraTransmit] FOREIGN KEY([PioniraTransmitId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PioniraTransmit] ([PioniraTransmitId])
```

Please note that Pionira.Api is not using/accessing my DB.

Comment: If I update only the "mother" table (PioniraTransmit), it doesn't trigger any exception. If I only update the "daughter" table (JsonMessages), it is the same 2/3 exception rate. I assume that when I update the JsonMessages table, the entity framework is aware of an implicit change in the PioniraTransmit table and is misbehaving. I've tried to put the 2 entries in the modified state as well without success ( db.Entry(...).State = EntityState.Modified )